# Predictive algorithm validation

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models

In putting a binary 1/0 predictive algorithm into production, what are the consequences where only the positive (1) predictions are checked, meaning only true or false positives are detected, and then fed back into training the model? Will that bias the algorithm in any way so that it progressively gets worse and worse because it never sees true or false negatives?

Comment: What is the feedback? Is it updating the algorithm only if it makes error or is it updating the algorithm with the new data irrespective of how the algorithm performed? Depending on the situation, the effect may be different.

Comment: Feedback is used irrespectively, right or wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am thinking of the following two points:

- You are observing the true labels and their associated predictors, a.k.a the pair $y_i,x_i$ only when the algorithm is predicting a label of $1$. The algorithm is updated regardless of whether it made an error or not. This means that there is no feedback on mistakes (like in online learning). We get new data irrespective of our prediction performance.
- The question we need to ask is then: *Does the algorithm's output influence the data source?* If the algorithm is not influencing the source, then this aspect where we 'conditionally observe new data' will not bias the algorithm by itself (everything else held constant).

Comment: Thanks for your response. Just to clarify, what do you mean when you say "influence the data source"? Once the algorithm goes live, it only gets fed examples where it had predicted 1's, since those are the only ones being checked. Does that "influence the data source"?

Comment: No that does not influence the data source. By influence, I mean, if the output of the algorithm (lets say an ad) affects the data source (say user behavior such as click/no click) which is then fed back to update the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm which never received 0's will be grossly biased and predict amost exclusively 1's.

Comment: the algorithm is receiving 0s and 1s according to the OP. It is only that it is seeing these 0s and 1s when the algorithm output is 1.

Comment: Then it will be biased another way (toward 0's).